# Can I clean Incredibuild agents "File cache"?

Tags: caching, incredibuild

In Incredibuild coordinator, some agents have warning "Larger file cache recommended".
The file cache is set to more then 4000 MB and I don't want to enlarge it.
Can I clear the cache content?
what is the effect of clearing the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the cache content although you don't have to. IncrediBuild will manage the cache automatically for you and will delete old content while adding new content.

Clearing the cache once in a while is possibile and will ensure that you don't have very old data which is no longer relevant in the cache.
You can either clear the cache on all agents at once by running the following command from the machine on which your IncrediBuild Coordinator is installed:

```
xgCoordConsole.exe /resetallfilecaches
```

You can also clear the cache of a specific Agent, either by selecting this Agent (or multiple Agents) in the Coordinator Monitor → right click → File cache → Clear contents 
or by running the command: "*IBConsole.exe /Reset*" on the machine from which you'd like to reset the cache.

You won't notice any difference after clearing the cache. The only affect clearing the cache can have is that some future tasks may take a little bit longer on the first time they are executed on a helper machine which its cache was cleared.

Proper disclosure: the writer is an IncrediBuild employee